# VB.net 2010 - SCCM 2007: Create package 1 level below Packages

Tags: vb.net, sccm

I have an application that entering package name and source location, will create a package in SCCM 2007.  It creates it fine at the root of Packages (under software distribution) but I want to create the package under a subfolder called "Windows 7".  As always thanks for the help.

```
            objPackage = SWbemServices.Get("SMS_Package").SpawnInstance_()

            objPackage.Name = PackageName
            objPackage.PkgSourcePath = SourcePath
            objPackage.PkgSourceFlag = 2
            objPackage.PkgFlags = 536870912
            objPackagePath = objPackage.Put_
```

Comment: How about moving them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sxse6kc(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Not sure that moving the source files would work, need to move the package down one level.

Comment: I thought I could do something like this...objPackagePath = "Windows 7\" & objPackage.Put_...but no worky

Comment: Try: `objPackage.Path` instead

Comment: objPackage.Path = "Windows 7\" & objPackage.Put_ ....still no worky

Comment: Perhaps a separate function to move the object down a level?